# Mutual information when Y is a function of X

Tags: information-theory

Mutual Information [is defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).  What is the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ when Y is a function of X, or vice versa?  Can I see a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You know that, in general, $I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|X)$.
 When $Y$ is a function of $X$ (or viceversa) you should be able to write $H(Y|X)$, or $H(X|Y)$.